# How to prevent Cakephp from flattening level 1 associations

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Suppose I have the following models. Users, Posts, and Comments. Users has many Posts. Posts have many Comments. If I try the following in the Posts controller:

```
$post = $this->Post->find('first', array('contain' => array('Comment')));
```

I get an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    'Post' => array(
        'postfield1',
        'postfield2',
        'etc'
    ),
    'Comment' => array(
        [0] => array('firstcommentfield1', 'etcfields'),
        [1] => array('secondcommentfield1', 'etcfields'),
    )
)
```

But if I run the following from the Users controller,

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('contain' => array('Post' => array('Comment'))));
```

and then look at the first post for a user `$user['Post'][0]` I get the following

```
array(

    'Post' => array(
        'postfield1',
        'postfield2',
        'etc'
        'Comment' => array(
            [0] => array('firstcommentfield1', 'etcfields'),
            [1] => array('secondcommentfield1', 'etcfields'),
        )
    ),
)
```

This makes it difficult to write functions that act on posts without doing formatting manually first.

Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Are you trying to get the same result as above or do you try to flatten the array?

Comment: I'd prefer if the results were not flattened at all, but I don't mind either way as long as it's consistent for level 1 associations and further down. Right now I'm working around it by writing functions assuming the non flat version and de-flattening the level 1 associations.

Comment: Found an older question with the same issue, but that one has no accepted answer either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159465/cakephp-model-query-return-data-formating